# Какой картографический движок лучше: Google Maps, OpenStreetMaps или MapBox для адаптивного веб-сервиса?

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, leafletjs, mapbox

Вопрос адресован знатокам ГИС и движков Google Maps, Map Box, Open Street Maps.

На каком движке лучше реализовать картографический веб-сервис с точки зрения:

- отрисовки и нанесения слоев;
- взаимодействия с библиотекой Leaflet JS;
- быстродействия;
- лицензии на использование.